# SQL Server code to add time to date time if after certain time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am NEW to SQL Server coding, so please be kind.

I am trying to look at a column and if the time is after 11am then I need to add 1 day to the date and display the new date. If prior to 11am, it doesn't need to add a day, but instead just show the date itself.

As you can see in the picture the "FDP Date" is adding a day no matter what time it shows (IE:lines 3 & 4). As if the time is before 11am it show not add any time.

Please let me know if you can help.

Thank you in advance,
Brian

Code:

```
SELECT 
    [ReceiptDate],
    [DeptRcptDate],
    CASE 
       WHEN DeptRcptDate >= '11:00:00' 
          THEN DATEADD (DAY, 1, DeptRcptDate)
       WHEN DeptRcptDate < '11:00:00' 
          THEN (DeptRcptDate)
       ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS "FDP Date",
    [OutcomeLtrDate],
    CASE 
       WHEN OutcomeLtrDate >= '16:00:00' 
          THEN (OutcomeLtrDate) + 1
       WHEN OutcomeLtrDate < '16:00:00' 
          THEN (OutcomeLtrDate)
       ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS "LDP Date"
```

*[Picture of (same) code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN8bx.gif)*

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `CASE` statement with `DATEPART`

```
declare @date datetime = '20160801 11:01:00'

select
    case 
        when datepart(hour,@date) >= 11 
        then dateadd(day,1,@date)
        else @date
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

`'11:00:00'` is 11am of the zero date ([January 1, 1753](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)). Obviously all your dates are greater than that.

If you want to compare times only, cast to [time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) first:

```
case when cast(DeptRcptDate as time(0)) >= '11:00:00' then dateadd(d, 1, DeptRcptDate)
```

Answer (score -2):

You're checking a datetime against a string contaiing a time. I'm not surprised it's giving unexpected results.

Get the time portion of your datetime with datepart(), and compare that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017